# Speed Up Parsing Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, parsing, refactoring

I'm trying to parse some ddump files, could you please help me speed up my algorithm?
It takes 216 ms for each loop!! that is way too much. I would like to have it around 40-50 ms per loop.   Maybe by using RegExp?

Here is my algrithm:

```
 while (pos < EntireFile.Length && (/*curr = */EntireFile.Substring(pos, EntireFile.Length - pos)).Contains(" class"))
            {
                w.Reset();
                w.Start();
                pos = EntireFile.ToLower().IndexOf(" class", pos) + 6;
                int end11 = EntireFile.ToLower().IndexOf("extends", pos);
                if (end11 == -1)
                    end11 = EntireFile.IndexOf("\r\n", pos);
                else
                {
                    int end22 = EntireFile.IndexOf("\r\n", pos);
                    if (end22 < end11)
                        end11 = end22;
                }
                //string opcods = EntireFile.Substring(pos, EntireFile.Length - pos);
                string Cname = EntireFile.Substring(pos, end11 - pos).Trim();
                pos += (end11 - pos) + 7;
                pos = EntireFile.IndexOf("{", pos) +1;
```

`int count = 1;
            string searching = EntireFile.Substring(pos, EntireFile.Length - pos);
            int searched = 0;
            while (count != 0)
            {
                if (searching[searched] == '{')
                    count++;
                else if (searching[searched] == '}')
                    count--;

                searched++;
            }
            string Content = EntireFile.Substring(pos, searched);
            tlist.Add(new TClass() { ClassName = Cname, Content = Content });
            pos += searched;

            if (pos % 3 == 0)
            {
                double prc = ((double)pos) * 100d / ((double)EntireFile.Length);
                int prcc = (int)Math.Round(prc);
                wnd.UpdateStatus(prcc);
                wnd.Update();
            }
            mils.Add((int)w.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am curious to know what format the dump file is.  What's the file size? Is there a sample of the data you can share?

Comment: Moving ´EntireFile.ToLower()´ outside the loop would be a reasonable start, but you should probably ask a profiler where it hurts the most. If you proved sample data and a complete working program someone might have the time to play with it.

Comment: Its a Nemo 440 dump file, but I didn't want to post it originally because it could produce a morallical discussion about decompiling...

Comment: Using regexps, IndexOf, Substring and alike does not count as "parsing" at all. Why don't you use some more conventional parsing approach? A recursive descent parsing, at least?

Comment: I suspect what the OP really needs is a fast lexer.  Most of his time is spent picking out strings, which is what lexers do extremely well, and extremely fast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, doing this multiple times

```
EntireFile.ToLower()
```

certainly will not help. There are several things you can do:

1. Perform costly operations (`ToLower`, `IndexOf`, etc) only once and cache the results if possible.
2. Do not narrow down on the input you are processing with `SubString`, this will kill your performance. Rather, keep a separate `int parseStart` value and use that as an additional parameter to all of your `IndexOf` calls. In other words, keep track of the part of the file you have parsed manually instead of taking a smaller substring each time.

Comment: Just to add to this...put the result of that method in a variable and reuse it.  Otherwise you taking the entire file and having to process everything to lower case everytime you call it.

Comment: @alex: Of course, take substrings if you need them for your results. Just don't take them for intermediate processing.

Comment: +1.  String manipulation is expensive.  Caching and reusing results like you suggest should help a lot.  Of course the `ToLower()` call can be taken out of the loop entirely and stored in a separate variable... `var LowerCaseFile = EntireFile.ToLower();`

Comment: Ok. I'll test performance again after moving toLower() outside the loop and taking a EntireFile offset.

Comment: **WOW** I cant believe it! Taking ToLower() out of the loop and using a virtual "substring" index instead of .Substring() reduced the average loop time to 1,644 ms! Thank you so much. You saved my day :-)

Comment: @alex: Glad to help. Just remember not to do that in the future :)

Comment: @alex: If you are surprised that taking `ToLower()` out of the loop helped so much, you should read [this great article on "hidden" loops](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) (and try not to get insulted by the title of the article). :-)

Answer (score 1):

The performance problems you have are in large related to overhead from all the string copy operations.

There are overloads that let's you specify the valid range of your string operations if you eliminate the copying by simply using an index to virtually substring the entire string that will make a difference.

Also, case-insensitive comparison are not made by lowering or upping the string! You use the `StringComparer` class or `StringComparsion` enumeration. There are many string overloads that let's you specify whether to consider case-sensitivity.

Indexing a string repeatedly using the square bracket notation is also very expensive. If you look at the implementation of the string operations in .NET they always turn the search string into a char array because that's faster to work with. However, that means that a lot of copying is still taking place even for read only search operations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a profiling tool to zero in on the part of your code that is slowing you down.

JetBrains dotTrace is one profiling product that has helped immensely with this kind of a task.

Comment: Ants profiler is another alternative, both come in time limited trials.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from Jon, as I understand it, anything in your while () portion of your code will execute on each loop. So it may be faster for you to figure out a way to not have it recalculate

```
EntireFile.Substring(pos, EntireFile.Length - pos)).Contains(" class")
```

on each iteration of the while loop. Additionally, what exactly are you trying to parse? Is it a normal text file? You haven't given many details. One method I like to use to parse text files is to load the entire file into an array of strings using '\n' as a delimiter. Then I can quickly step through the array and parse the contents. If I need to, I can store an array index and quickly refer to a previous line.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, you can change

```
while (pos < EntireFile.Length && (/*curr = */EntireFile.Substring(pos, EntireFile.Length - pos)).Contains(" class"))
{
 ...
}
```

to

```
var loweredEntireFile = EntireFile.ToLower();

while (pos < loweredEntireFile.Length && 
       Regex.IsMatch(loweredEntireFile, " class",   
       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
{
...

    // we just need to process the rest of the file
    loweredEntireFile = loweredEntireFile.Substring(pos, loweredEntireFile.Length - pos));
}
```

then change

```
pos = EntireFile.ToLower().IndexOf(" class", pos) + 6;
int end11 = EntireFile.ToLower().IndexOf("extends", pos);
```

to

```
var matches = Regex.Matchs(loweredEntireFile, " class", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
pos = matches.First().Index;

matches = Regex.Matchs(loweredEntireFile, "extends", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var end11 = matches.First().Index;
```

as other suggested,

```
var loweredEntiredFile = EntiredFile.ToLower();
```

should be done once outside the while, and

```
loweredEntireFile = loweredEntireFile.Substring(pos, loweredEntireFile.Length - pos));
```

need to be done in the end of the while